# Excel formula expertise required with if,indirect,countif

Tags: excel-formula

Hi i want to check a file which will have 3 end results Simple, Simple Wt. and Complex Wt.the conditions are as follows:

1.If the cusip is coming once then Simple variable
2.If the cusip is coming more then 1 then its complex variable

If condition 2 comes then following check also required:
in 2 or more cusip 1 is prime then prime will be simple
if the reset and rate is same for all then simple variable
if reset is different then directly wt complex
if reset same but rate is different then simple wt

If you want i can attach the excel file as well.i tried but couldnt accomplish the end goal.

[The image of the same has been attached now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsbHh.jpg)

Comment: You really need to show source data and examples of the conditions and results you want...

Comment: please have a look incase you got what you wanted??